# mysql crashing on certain actions

Tags: mysql, database-administration

We have a MySQL database that periodically crashes and outputs the following stack trace in the error log.

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2c)[0xec198c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x461)[0x799e11]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf5a0)[0x7fef65d425a0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN10Field_blob15copy_blob_valueEP11st_mem_root+0x25)[0x7dcfb5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z25mysql_prepare_blob_valuesP3THDR4ListI4ItemEP11st_mem_root+0x2b8)[0xe08aa8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12write_recordP3THDP5TABLEP9COPY_INFOS4_+0x9c0)[0xe097b0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN14Sql_cmd_insert12mysql_insertEP3THDP10TABLE_LIST+0x825)[0xe0a225]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN14Sql_cmd_insert7executeEP3THD+0xc2)[0xe0aa62]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THDb+0x18d7)[0xc998b7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDP12Parser_state+0x5d5)[0xc9fa25]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_commandP3THDPK8COM_DATA19enum_server_command+0xaca)[0xca057a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x1b7)[0xca1fc7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_connection+0x2a0)[0xd66830]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x1b4)[0xeda334]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7de5)[0x7fef65d3ade5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fef63e9830d]
```

What is the best way to proceed from here?

Comment: What I do is search bugs.mysql.com for reports of a similar stack trace. This one looks similar https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79243

Comment: Looking into the bug logs for MySQL it looks like the fix was placed for this.
Related fixed in 5.7.21, 8.0.4:

Following an INSERT statement with BLOB values in the ON DUPLICATE
KEY UPDATE clause that failed with a constraint violation, a similar
statement with no reason to return an error could cause a server
exit.

Comment: Please post (to pastebin.com, if not here), RAM  nnn TB/GB/MB on your Host server, indicate DEDICATED or SHARED w other apps? 

current complete my.cnf/ini and php.ini (if used)
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
C) complete current text of error log
to assist in determining why the pfs_spawn_thread failed.  We can see a BLOB was involved, leading to the failure.